# How to login with email and phonenumber fields in asp.net core razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, razor-pages

In asp.net core razorpage the SignInManager have PasswordSignInAsync method to login just with username but I want login with PhoneNumber or Email and etc..
This is my code for login:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Username, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

And this is PasswordSignInAsync method which I can't change it because it is locked in asp.net core:

```
public virtual Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
        {
            throw null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a second overload that you have to use:

```
public virtual async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
```

Combine this with [UserManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0) like that:

```
// find user by Email
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);

// or find user by PhoneNumber
//var user = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.PhoneNumber == Input.PhoneNumber);

if (user != null)
{
    var result = _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
}
```